# Word for the opposite of universality

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, academia

I am looking for a word that implies the unique/non-translatable aspects of a specific place or culture. It's for an academic paper, so feel free to pull suggestions from theory etc.

> The author argues that the text does not appeal to universality but, on the contrary, to {{what is local/not shared by others}}.

Current option is "locality" or "the local" but neither feel quite right.

Comment: Or perhaps combine your answers into "the particularity of a place/culture"....though not exactly one word...

Comment: How “local” are we talking?. Is it too localized for ***regionality***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the opposite of *universality* is ***[particularity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/particularity)***, which means

> The quality of being individual.

In your example, it reads:

> The author argues that the text does not appeal to universality but, on the contrary, to the *particularity* of the place/culture.

If you really want to emphasize the "non-translatability" aspect, you might go with ***[haecceity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/haecceity)*** (*/hek-SAY-ih-TEE/*), which means:

> The property of being a unique and individual thing.

It comes from the Latin word for *[thisness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haecceity)* and strongly connotes a thing's (almost metaphysical) uniqueness.

In your example it reads:

> The author argues that the text does not appeal to universality but, on the contrary, to the *haecceity* of the place/culture.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with *specificity*. An alternative is some form of the word *context*.

[Here's](http://web.stanford.edu/group/ipc/pubs/2002ElfenbeinMeta.pdf) a well-cited academic paper that uses universality and specificity in its title, for instance.

In your example,

> The author argues that the text does not appeal to universality but, on the contrary, to specificity.

If this is what you're looking for, I'd also suggest adding what the text specifically applies *to*.

Comment: Thank you for the paper example! Very useful. And a variation on "context" is a good option, actually.

Answer (score 2):

**singularity**

[Oxford English dictionaries:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/singularity)

> 1. The state, fact, quality, or condition of being (single or unique)

*Singularity* also has the added connotation of *singular*'s definition of *exceptionally good or great*.

---

**relativity**

[Oxford English dictionaries:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/relativity)

> 1. The absence of standards of absolute and universal application:
>      *moral relativity*

[***Cultural relativism*** is the principle that an individual person's beliefs and activities should be understood by others in terms of that individual's own culture. ~ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_relativism)

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider something simple like idiomatic?

> The author argues that the text does not appeal to universality but, on the contrary, to the *idiomatic*.

Another option you might consider is:

> The author argues that the text does not appeal to universality but, on the contrary, to the *parochial*.

Comment: "Idiomatic" doesn't connote place, at least for me. "Parochial" is interesting (even if implicitly negative).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen parochial frequently used as the opposite of universal- it too means local or regional.
"...the text does not appeal to universality but, on the contrary, to parochiality" doesn't sound too awkward.

Comment: Hmmm, I still don't think I will use it (we are talking about something that doesn't make sense in a western context, so the heavily christian "parochial" just doesn't work) but will tuck away for future reference.